# Custom Swift Formatter for phone numbers

Tags: swift, macos

I require a simple phone number formatter in Swift to add to an NSTextField.

I am having difficulty understanding the documentation and examples, particularly for the getObjectValue(_:, for:, errorDescription) -> Bool function's obj?.pointee usage. The concept of an AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer? was difficult from the documentation and I cannot find much about custom Swift Formatters on the web. I looked at Marmel Roy's PhoneNumberKit but it seems too complex for my needs, and did not describe how to add to a formatter directly.

```
override func getObjectValue(_ obj: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<AnyObject?>?, for string: String, errorDescription error: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSString?>?) -> Bool {

      obj?.pointee = someConversionToInternalString(typedString)
        return true
    }
```

The above failed to work, repeatedly just storing an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

After some work, I worked out how to do this. I'm hoping it will save others time in doing this.
The key in my solution was to store the "object" as a Cocoa object (ie a la objective C type); here as an NSString rather than String.
Here is some complete sample code that does (simple) formatting of phone numbers that sufficed for my conditions.

```
import Foundation

class PhoneFormatter: Formatter {

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }

    func reduceToPhoneCharacters(string: String) -> String {
        let plusSign = string.prefix(1) == "+"

        // remove any non-digit characters
        let str = string.digits
        return "\(plusSign ? "+" : "")\(str)"
    }

    func displayString(string: String) -> String? {

        // take a string of symbols and convert into a formatted phone number (US, Aust, Europe)
        if string.isBlank || !string.isPhoneCharacters { return string } // will see if it improves

        let plusSign = string.prefix(1) == "+"

        // remove any non-digit characters
        let str = string.digits

        // international, + at start, recognise only US, Australian, NZ or European
        if plusSign {
            // USA
            if str.prefix(1) == "1" {
                return "+" + str.substring(start: 0, length: 1) + " (" + str.substring(start: 1, length: 3) + ") " + str.substring(start: 4, length: 3) + "-" + str.substring(start: 7, length: 4)
            }
            // Australia
            if str.prefix(2) == "61" || str.prefix(2) == "64" {
                return "+" + str.substring(start: 0, length: 3) + "-" + str.substring(start: 3, length: 4) + "-" + str.substring(start: 7, length: 4)
            }
            // Others? eg +44-123-456789
            return "+" + str.substring(start: 0, length: 2) + "-" + str.substring(start: 3, length: 4) + "-" + str.substring(start: 7, length: 10)
        }
        // mobile if begins with 04
        if str.prefix(2) == "04" {
            return str.substring(start: 0, length: 4) + "-" + str.substring(start: 4, length: 3) + "-" + str.substring(start: 7, length: 3)
        }
        // interstate
        if str.prefix(1) == "0" {
            return str.substring(start: 0, length: 2) + "-" + str.substring(start: 2, length: 4) + "-" + str.substring(start: 6, length: 4)
        }
        // 1800 or 1300 numbers
        if str.prefix(4) == "1800" || str.prefix(4) == "1300" {
            return str.substring(start: 0, length: 1) + "-" + str.substring(start: 1, length: 3) + "-" + str.substring(start: 4, length: 3) + "-" + str.substring(start: 7, length: 4)
        }
        // else Victoria substring
        return str.substring(start: 0, length: 4) + "-" + str.substring(start: 4, length: 4)
    }

    override func string(for obj: Any?) -> String? {
        // take a string of symbols and convert into a formatted phone number (US, Aust, Europe)
        guard let str = obj as? NSString else { return nil }
        return displayString(string: str as String)
    }

    override func getObjectValue(_ obj: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<AnyObject?>?, for string: String, errorDescription error: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSString?>?) -> Bool {

        obj?.pointee = reduceToPhoneCharacters(string: string) as NSString
        return true
    }

    override func editingString(for obj: Any) -> String? {
        if let str = obj as? NSString {
            return str as String
        }
        return nil
    }

    override func isPartialStringValid(_ partialString: String, newEditingString newString: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSString?>?, errorDescription error: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSString?>?) -> Bool {
        return partialString.isPhoneCharacters || partialString == ""
    }
}

// separate +String.swift file for extensions
import Foundation

extension String {}

    var digits: String {
        return components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted).joined()
    }

    var isPhoneCharacters: Bool {
        return !isEmpty && range(of: "[^+\\d]", options: .regularExpression) == nil
    }    

    func substring(start: Int, length : Int) -> String {
        if (count > start + length) {
            let startAtIndex = index(startIndex, offsetBy: start)
            return String(self[startAtIndex...index(startAtIndex, offsetBy: length - 1)])
        }
        if count > start {
            let startAtIndex = index(startIndex, offsetBy: start)
            return String(self[startAtIndex...])
        }
        return ""
    }

}
```

And to use it programmatically, eg:

```
        @IBOutlet weak var phoneTextField: NSTextField!
        phoneTextField.formatter = PhoneFormatter()
```

I have edited this to remove redundant code and use the editingString(for:) function.

Comment: What are you formatting here, for what country and/or number format is this code relevant? And don't use NSString instead of String.

Comment: I am providing the phone formatting as an example of using the Swift Formatter. The phone number code is a simple way of formatting for the common phone numbers we use. If more extensive phone formatting is needed, then I guess PhoneNumberKit code could be used in this, but I have not implemented this, since I don't need it.

Comment: And with respect to NSString. I could not get this to work using the native Swift String class as the internal string which is stored as an "object" by the Formatter. For some reason, it only worked with the internal string being an NSString.

Comment: And I should have added the way to use it programmatically. Since it uses a singleton, it can be re-used multiple times: